# android -does calling finish from activity destroy hosted fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentmanager, fragment-lifecycle

I have an 'Activity A' which host a 'Fragment B'.  Please confirm that if I call A.finish() then 'fragment B 'gets destroyed.  The fragment B would already be added to the fragment manager.  I realize that a fragment is a sub-activity but i want to know do i have to tell the fragment manager to release the fragment in Ondestroy or is it all taken care of ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
but i want to know do i have to tell the fragment manager to 
release the fragment in Ondestroy or is it all taken care of ?
```

By default when you call `finish` in your activity it will automatically call `onDestroy` method of all the fragments that is attach to the activity thus **destroying it**, so no need to worry about destroying the fragment in `onDestroy` method of your activity.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

```
For example, when the activity is paused, so are all fragments in it, 
and when the activity is destroyed, so are all fragments.
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are the Subactivities of an activity. So whenever we will call the finish the fragment associated with it will also get destroyed without notifying FragmentManager.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the fragment is destroyed. From the [Android Fragment guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

> For example, when the activity is paused, so are all fragments in it,
>   and when the activity is destroyed, so are all fragments.

Comment: Should people use onDestroy or onDestroyView ? And is the activity still available via getActivity on each of them?

Comment: @ android developer ondestroyview is good when the activity is stiill in memory.  the fragments view is relased from memory but the fragment object itself remains until ondestroy is called.